# Having no luck with Apache Felix deploy

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to deploy a particular version of a bundle through Apache Felix's **obr** *deploy* command.

I want to install version 3.1.10 of File Install, but unfortunately **deploy** does not understand versions (when using @ to specify them):

```
g! deploy "Apache Felix File Install"@3.1.10
Unknown bundle - Apache Felix File Install@3.1.10
```

Neither does it work if I try the semicolon:

```
g! deploy "Apache Felix File Install";3.1.10
Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Apache Felix File Install (3.0.2)

Deploying...done.
gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: 3.1.10
```

Anybody has any idea what's going on?

P.S.:
BONUS points for anybody installing "File Install 3.0.2", and then placing a jar of "3.1.10" into the load directory (thereby installing another "File Install" bundle) - and then deleting the "3.0.2" version! Sadly this does not work, as "File Install" always suspends itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me:

```
g! list -v file
Apache Felix File Install [org.apache.felix.fileinstall] (3.0.2, 3.0.0, 2.0.8, 2.0.4,     2.0.0, 1.2.0, 1.0.0, 0.9.2, 0.9.0)
g! deploy "Apache Felix File Install"@3.0.0
Target resource(s):
-------------------
   Apache Felix File Install (3.0.0)

Optional resource(s):
---------------------
   Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service (1.2.4)
   Apache Felix Log Service (1.0.0)

Deploying...done.
g!
```

It looks like you are trying to deploy a version of File Install that isn't in the OBR repo...

Comment: How do I know if it is in the OBR repo or not?

Comment: Above I use "list -v", which is verbose mode, to list all versions available in the repo.

Comment: I understand, but I still think the error is "wrong" in a sense that it doesn't say "Version not available" - but simply installs a random version. Thanks.

Comment: It does not install a random version, when you used the proper syntax for version (i.e., "Apache Felix File Install"@3.1.10) it told you it was an unknown bundle. When you used improper syntax (i.e., "Apache Felix File Install";3.1.10), it deployed the highest matching version it found and then Gogo interpreted the semi-colon as a command separator and told you it cannot find the 3.1.10 command.

Comment: Also how come there are two "Richard S. Hall"s, which one is real? http://stackoverflow.com/users/422347/richard-s-hall